# Anaconda latest version error while trying to open jupyter notebook from the prompt

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Hi

I uninstalled my older version of Anaconda using the control panel in Windows , and installed the latest version today (**Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64**). However, when i type

`jupyter notebook`

on the anaconda prompt, it gives the following error

`C:\Users\kaushikb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kaushikb\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\kaushikb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in 
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\kaushikb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in 
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\kaushikb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\kaushikb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\kaushikb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\kaushikb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\kaushikb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.`

Was this issue discussed already here? Please point me to the correct thread if this is a duplicate question. If not -- please help me to fix this problem. My Windows Specs are:

[image]

--- regards

Comment: Have you installed jupyter notebook again?

Comment: @NavanK. No. I haven't. Isn't it by default installed with Anaconda?

Comment: No. It's not I guess .

Comment: @NavanK. I tried installing it - but it says its already updated. But the problem still recurs again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same issue but this worked for me:

**step 1:** add **YOUR_ANACONDA_ROOT/bin** to PATH in the environment variables (for me it is C:\Users\tejkr\anaconda3\bin)

**step 2:** open anaconda prompt as admin and run these commands

*pip3 install --upgrade pip*

followed by

For Python 2:
*pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter --user*

For Python 3:
*pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter --user*

then execute **jupyter notebook** in anaconda prompt or your activated env

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked beautifully, but I had to skip the second step. So basically, what I did was like you said, add the anaconda bin path to env variables and then run the Python3 force reinstall Jupyter command you gave.